# MIPS Assembly - Instruction String to Hex

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I'm working on something in Assembly where it takes a string for an instruction, such as

```
add $t1, $t0, $t1
```

and prints out the instruction in hex.

I scan the string piece by piece, with add being recognized first. Add has an op code of 001000 (6 bits)

t1 is scanned, and it compares itself to the data section, and it has a value of 5 bits 01001, same with t0 with 01000, and t1 again at 01001. All these are scanned in order so precedence isn't that important as far as I can tell.

From then, I know I need to smush these together somehow and then convert from binary to hex. My problem is, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to be storing these binary values as they're read. Whether to store them in the data section, which doesn't seem right due to their odd bit sizes, or if there is some easier way.

Honestly, I don't know much about bit shifting, so the answer may lay in there.

Here's my code. It's very much a WIP

```
#text segement
    .text
    .globl main

main:
    li $t0, 0   #pointer for input
    li $t1, 0   #pointer for storing
    li $t2, 0   #parser
    li $t3, 0   #temp hold t0
    li $t4, 0   #hold reg num
    li $t8, 0   #number of reg

    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, input
    li $a1, 32
    syscall

    la $a0, input

    li $v0, 10  #end
    syscall


scan:
    lb $t2, input($t0)
    #beq $t2,'$',pass
    beq $t2,' ',pass

    beq $t2,'*',next
    beq $t2,',',next

    beq $t2,10,end

    sb $t2, inst($t1)

    addi $t1,1
    addi $t1,1

    j scan

next:
    move $t3, $t0 #store in t3 temporarily
    move $t0, $0
    move $t1, $0
    move $t2, $0
next2:
    lb $t2, inst($t0)
    beq $t2,'$',register    #t2 = $, reg
    bge $t2,65,funct        #t2 >= 65, funct
    ble $t2,57,num          #57 >= t2, num

funct:
    lb $t2, inst($t0)
    beq $t2, 'a', afunct
    beq $t2, 's', sfunct
    beq $t2, 'm', afunct
afunct:
    lb $t2, inst($t0)

sfunct:

mfunct:

num:
    lb $t2, inst($t0)


register:
    addi $t0, 1
    lb $t2, inst($t0)   #get reg type

    addi $t0, 1         #increase pointer

    lb $t4, inst($t0)   #find reg num and convert to t4
    addi $t4, -48

    beq $t2, 't', treg
    beq $t2, 'a', sreg
    beq $t2, 'v', vreg

treg:
    mult $t4,4
    mflo $t4
    lw $t2, tr($t4)
areg:
    mult $t4,4
    mflo $t4
    lw $t2, ar($t4)

vreg:
    mult $t4,4
    mflo $t4
    lw $t2, vr($t4)

.data
input:  .space 32
inst:   .space 32
tr: 01000,01001,01010,01011,01100,01101,01111
sr: 00100
vr: 00010

a:  001000
```

Comment: After doing some reading I understand how and what bit shifting does but I've been unable to apply it to my problem. Does anyone have anymore guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is in bit shifting and logical OR'ing. You shift the various pieces indicated by the components of the instruction into their appropriate positions in the resulting instruction word and logically OR them together.  (Assuming the other bits are 0, adding would be equivalent.

Realize that what you are doing is writing (a trivial case of) an assembler.

Comment: is there anyway you can expand on what you've just said a little more, possibly with an example? i really appreciate your help!

Comment: See lecture notes from a good undergrad CS course, for example starting at page 14 of http://6004.csail.mit.edu/Fall09/handouts/L11-4up.pdf Different processor but same general idea.